# Capture error from command while using execvp(cmd, args)

Tags: c

```
p = fork;
if (p == 0){
   execvp(args[0], args);
}
else {
   wait(&status);
}
```

If the command given returns an error, how do I print this out? For example if I gave execvp the command "ls -8" how do I have it print to standard out

ls: invalid option -- '8'

Comment: nvm... it already does this lol :(

Comment: I think its not stdout but stderr & it is displayed by the child process.

Answer (score 0):

When you fork, the forked process will share the same file descriptors for stdin/out/err. This means that whatever it prints to stdout will go to stdout. Same for stderr.

exec*() functions replace the current process.

As such, when the "ls -8" prints something to stderr it will go to stderr. You'll have to shortcircuit stderr and stdout to have stderr go to stdout.

You need something like this:

```
p = fork;
if (p == 0){
   close(2); /* close stderr */
   dup(1); /* duplicate stdout as stderr */
   execvp(args[0], args);
}
else {
   wait(&status);
}
```